# branch & merging

Tags: git

Here's the scenario:

1. development branch (current commit dated 11/15)
2. then, i've make a feature branch (FeatureA) from development (with current commit dated 11/15)
3. modify & work in the feature branch (FeatureA)
4. other user, committed/merged to the development branch  (current commit dated 11/16)

So, I update my local copy of development branch (dated 11/16).

`command: git pull origin development`

But my feature branch (FeatureA) is still based from the previous commit (date 11/15) of development. right?

Question: how to update my feature branch from the updated code in development?

git merge development, this command?

Answer (score 1):

Either `git merge development` or `git rebase development`. Prefer the latter only after reading up on [rebasing](http://book.git-scm.com/4_rebasing.html), since it rewrites history.

Answer (score 0):

```
git fetch origin
```

should update your branch with the changes made to the code in development.

Comment: I'm afraid it won't - `git fetch origin` will update all the remote-tracking branches corresponding to the `origin` repository, but won't touch any of your local branches.

Comment: Ah.. I see. I was under the impression that the desired result was getting the changes on the remote development branch and updating the local development branch with those changes. Sorry I misunderstood.